# Selecting two tables that have the same columns

Tags: mysql

How can I execute a query in MySQL that returns two different tables with the same columns.

```
Table 1 columns: id, symbol, value
Table 2 columns: id, symbol, value
```

I have tried something like this, but it only return tbl1_c1

```
SELECT col1 as tbl1_c1 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE col1 = 'xyz' 
UNION ALL SELECT col1 as tbl2_col1 
FROM tbl2 
WHERE col1 = 'xyz'
```

expected outcome:
id, symbol, table_value, table_value2

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result. As er my understanding, you need a `join` not a `union all`

Comment: Are the values of `id` and `symbol` the same in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, symbol, value as table_value, NULL as table_value2
FROM tbl1
WHERE symbol = 'xyz'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, symbol, NULL as table_value, value as table_value2
FROM tbl2
WHERE symbol = 'xyz';
```